# Hyperref and multiple parts in a document

Tags: hyperref, numbering, footnotes

I am using the `article` document class with `amsthm` and `hyperref`. I have divided the article into parts. I would like the section under each part to start from 1. However, once I do that inserting `\setcounter{section}{0}` just after `\part{the_title}`, I get the references messed up. The \ref works fine in the first part but the \ref in the second part refers to refs in the first part and not to the ref belonging to that same section. How do I get around this?

This is what I have in mind:

Part I: Background

1 Section_1

2 Section_2

Part II: Methods

1 Section_1

2 Section_1

One more, I want to put "Typeset In Latex"($Typeset in {\bf \LaTeX}$) in the footnote in the title page. However, this footnote is numbered which I do not want. I was able to suppress the numbering using `\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext`, but the rest the footnote numbers get suppressed in the article. How do I suppress the footnote number just for one time.

Thank you.

P.S. I can swap the numbers using `\swapnumbers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scheme is not good, IMO. In a phrase such as "as seen in section 1", what section are you referring to? And what will your reader think? That's why the standard classes don't reset chapter (book, amsbook) or section (article, amsart) numbers after `\part`.

Do your readers a favor, if you really insist for such a scheme: say

```
\numberwithin{section}{part}
```

in the preamble so that references to sections will have the part number before them (and also hyperref will be happy).

An unnumbered footnote in the first page is obtained with the `\thanks` command; don't use `$...$` to get italics, there's `\emph{...}` or `\textit{...}` for that.

Comment: thank you very much for the full answer. Okay, I see the problem.{I didn't use $...$ to get italics. I thought I could latex here as I used to in Mathematics.SE}